# Recaptcha in one form is blocking another form

Tags: forms, asp.net-core-mvc, .net-core, recaptcha

I have two forms in a View, one of which has the `<recaptcha/>` tag included within the form, the other doesn't. Attempting to submit the form that doesn't have a recaptcha, is blocked by the recaptcha in the other form, which then states the error-message of not being validated.

I'm using the NuGet-package: PaulMiami.AspNetCore.Mvc.Recaptcha, .NET Core 1.1

```
<form method="post" asp-controller="Account" asp-action="Register" asp-route-returnurl="@ViewData["ReturnUrl"]">

...

<div>
    <div>
        <button type="submit">Submit</button>   <!-- Hitting this button, triggers the recaptchaErrorMessage to fire and block. -->
    </div>
</div>
</form>

<form asp-controller="Contact" asp-action="SendMessage">

...

<div>
    <recaptcha/>
    <span id="recaptchaErrorMessage"></span>
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was a bug, it was fixed in version 1.2.1, please update:

```
dotnet add package PaulMiami.AspNetCore.Mvc.Recaptcha --version 1.2.1
```